# Mongoose Schema in Typescript

Tags: typescript, mongoose, next.js, mongoose-schema

I am looking to create a user schema in TS.
so far I have seen people providing an interface which works fine until I add a message with
username.unique or required property.

no error code :-

```
import {model, models,Schema,Document } from "mongoose";

interface UserType extends Document{
    username : string,
    email : string,
    password : string,
}

const userSchema = new Schema<UserType>({
    username : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        trim : true,
        minlength : 3
    },
    email : {
        type :  String, 
        required : true,
        trim : true,
        lowercase : true,    
    },


})
```

but as soon as I add messages there is an squiggle error.

```
import {model, models,Schema,Document } from "mongoose";

interface UserType extends Document{
    username : string,
    email : string,
    password : string,
}

const userSchema = new Schema<UserType>({
    username : {
        type : String,
        required : [true, "Username is required"],
        unique : [true, "Username is already taken"],
        trim : true,
        minlength : 3
    },
    email : {
        type :  String, 
        required :[ true, "Email is required"],
        unique : [  true, "Email is already in use"],
        trim : true,
        lowercase : true,    
    },


})
```

error :

```
type hereType '{ type: StringConstructor; required: [true, string]; unique: (string | true)[]; trim: true; minlength: number; }' is not assignable to type 'SchemaDefinitionProperty<string> | undefined'.
  Types of property 'unique' are incompatible.
    Type '(string | true)[]' is not assignable to type 'number | boolean | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

I am looking if there is a way out to do this in an effective way .
OR is using hybrid JS + TS is a good practice.?

ps: this is a next.js project

Comment: What's the version of `mongoose`?

Comment: According to this documentation, `unique` is not a validator. Therefore, does it have error message functionality at all? https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#the-unique-option-is-not-a-validator https://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html#unique-doesnt-work

Comment: @LinDu  "mongoose": "^7.2.2",

Comment: @StuartNichols I got that documentation you linked here, but question is about passing type [boolean ,  string ] as a value , even in case of required property gives an error.

Comment: My point was that `[true, "Username is already taken"]` is not a valid value for the `unique` property. If you set that to `true`, do you still get an error for `required`?

Comment: @StuartNichols I got it. it worked as you said, there is no error for required after correcting unique.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, `[true, "message"]` is not a valid value for the `unique` property as it is not a validator as stated in the documentation below.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#the-unique-option-is-not-a-validator
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html#unique-doesnt-work

The `required` property works fine with `[true, "message"]`.

However, if you really want to override the typing and proceed anyway, you can make the error go away by casting the SchemaType to `any`:

**I do not recommend this approach**

```
import {model, models,Schema,Document } from "mongoose";

interface UserType extends Document{
    username : string,
    email : string,
    password : string,
}

const userSchema = new Schema<UserType>({
    username : {
        type : String,
        required : [true, "Username is required"],
        unique : [true, "Username is already taken"],
        trim : true,
        minlength : 3
    } as any,
    email : {
        type :  String, 
        required :[ true, "Email is required"],
        unique : [  true, "Email is already in use"],
        trim : true,
        lowercase : true,    
    } as any,
})
```